# exit(0) vs return 0

Tags: c++, return, destructor, exit

> When exit(0) is used to exit from program, destructors for locally
>   scoped non-static        objects are not called. But destructors are
>   called if return 0 is used.Note that static      objects will be
>   cleaned up even if we call exit().

There should be some reason behind this logic. i just want to know what it is? Thank you.

Comment: That's not at all the same question as the one cited above.  He's apparently familiar with the answers to the cited question (`exit` doesn't call local destructors.  He's asking why.

Comment: @JamesKanze Ok. We have been a little too quick on this one. Voting to reopen the question, removed downvote.

Comment: Even though the accepted answer in the linked-to question gives a hint ("exit() does not return") to the reason, I agree that it is certainly not a duplicate. It's an entirely different question.

Answer (score 8):

In the case of `exit( 0 )`, you're calling a function.  You
don't expect the destructors of local variables to be called if
you're calling a function.  And the compiler doesn't know,
a priori, that there is anything special about `exit( 0 )`.

In fact, this rationale really only applies to C++ before
exceptions.  The standard could redefine `exit()` to throw an
implementation defined exception with the argument, and specify
that the call to `main` is wrapped in a try block which catches
this exception, and passes the return code back to the system.
This would mean that `exit` have a completely different
semantics in C and in C++, however; at any rate, there's been no
proposal before the committee to make this change.