# Which one choose: exit or return?

Tags: c, return, return-value, exit

I know the difference between `return` and `exit()` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/461528/3185964)), but I don't know where and when to choose one instead of the other. For example from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15945783/3185964) answer I understand that `return` is a better choise, but from [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21269188/3185964) I understand the opposite.

An example: in this code (from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21267716/3185964) question) is it preferable to use `exit()` or `return`?

```
int read_file (char *filename, int **vet)
{
    FILE *fin;

    if ( !(fin = fopen(filename, "r")) )
    {
        perror(filename);
        return -1;
    }

    * vet = malloc (10 * sizeof(int));
    if ( *vet == NULL )
    {
        perror("Memory allocation error.\n");
        return -2;   
    }

    /* ... */

    return fclose(fin);
}

int main ()
{
    char filename[100];
    int *vet;

    if ( read_file(filename, &vet) )
        /* ??? exit(1) OR return -1 ??? */

    return 0;
}
```

And generally?

Comment: You wrote `exit(1) OR return -1 ???` -- `1` and `-1` are not equivalent.

Comment: @MikeW I had linked the same question in mine: it is different.

Comment: @user It is not different. There is a comprehensive explanation of the differences in that question. There is no right answer - it depends on what you are doing. In that context, your question has little meaning.

Comment: @user: No, not at all. The status value returned by the program should be exactly the same, whether it's returned via calling `exit` or executing a `return` statement. There's a convention of using negative values for error returns for some functions, but that does not apply to `main`. The only *portable* status values are `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. (And on Unix-like systems, negative values are mapped to the range 0..255 anyway, so `return -1;` might be equivalent to `return 255;`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, sorry: I wrote my comment before reading your response!

Comment: @KeithThompson:  "The status value returned by the program should be exactly the same, whether it's returned via calling exit or executing a return statement."  That's not strictly true.  See my answer on the original question.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Actually I believe it is strictly true, at least for conforming compilers. See my comment on [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27301635/827263) for details.

Comment: @KeithThompson:  You're right.  The standard requires this to be strictly true, but it puts some implementations into a no-win situation, so they don't strictly adhere to the standard in this regard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From within the `main` function, `exit(N)` and `return N;` are very nearly identical (but see below).

`exit()` terminates the entire execution of the program. `return` merely returns from the current function. (I know you said you know the difference, but I want to be complete).

If you're in `main`, you can use either one you like. The choice is a matter of style, and I don't think there's any agreement on what style is the best. You might consider using `exit` in case the code in `main` is later moved into some other function. I'd use `return` from `main` for more *normal* program termination.

Note that the value either passed to `exit` or used by `return` has a somewhat system-specific meaning. The value is returned to the calling environment. `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` denotes success; `EXIT_FAILURE` denotes failure. (`EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are macros defined in `<stdlib.h>`, the same header that defines the `exit` function).

Any other value will have a system-specific meaning. In particular, there have been systems (VMS in particular) on which `exit(1)` indicates success, not failure. On a Unix-like system, where `1` denotes failure, `EXIT_FAILURE` will be defined as 1.

You can use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE` with either `return` or `exit()`.

On the other hand, if you need to specify more than one kind of failure, `EXIT_FAILURE` won't be enough. On Unix-like systems, and probably on Windows, `0` denotes success, `1` denotes a more or less generic failure, and other small positive integers denote other kinds of failure. Feel free to use specific values if that's what you need; you *probably* don't care that your program may not work as expected on VMS. (I'd define constants for the various exit values you use, and clearly say what they all mean in the documentation.) Again, you can use either `exit()` or `return`, whichever is more convenient.

I said above that `exit(N)` and `return N` from `main()` are *almost* identical.

It's legal in C for `main` to call itself recursively. If your program is in `main`, but not in the initial invocation of `main`, then `return` will terminate the current execution of `main`, but will not terminate the program; it's just like `return` vs. `exit()` for any function other than `main`. Calling `main` recursively is almost always a bad idea, so this is worth being aware of, but not worth worrying about.

Also, `atexit()` can be used to register functions to be called automatically on program exit. Any such functions will be called whether the function terminates due to `exit()` or `return`. The difference (and it's an incredibly obscure one) is that `exit()` is called by `main`, and `return` immediately leaves `main`. So if one of your `atexit()`-registered functions refers to a local variable inside `main`, that variable will still exist if you called `exit()`, but not if you executed a `return` statement. You would have to go out of your way to make this happen, and there's no good reason to do so, so you almost certainly don't have to worry about this particular issue.

Comment: And if I wanted to differentiate errors? For example: how can I wrote a code like `exit(1)`, `exit(2)`, etc. with `EXIT_FAILURE`?

Comment: @user: You can't do that in an *entirely* portable manner. But for most systems (certainly including Linux and other Unix-like systems, and probably including Windows as well), `exit(1)` denotes a more or less generic failure, and 2 or higher denotes some more specific error (e.g., `grep` uses 0 for a match, 1 for no match, and 2 for an error such as a missing file). `EXIT_FAILURE` is probably equal to 1, but if you need specific numeric values, just write `exit(1)`, `exit(2)`, etc. (or `return 1`, `return 2`). I've updated my answer; see the 7th paragraph.

Comment: +1 for the `atexit` paragraph. I had never considered that difference in behaviour before.

Answer (score 1):

If used in the `main`, both will do the same, so I would choose `return 1` because it's simpler and works without any `#include`.

`exit` is handy when you want to terminate from a function or otherwise outside your `main` routine.

Comment: Yes, but the meaning of `return 1;` is system-specific. (On Unix, it denotes success; on VMS, it denotes failure). `return EXIT_FAILURE;` is more reliable and clearer, but it requires `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I completely agree with that. Only, the question was focused on `exit(1)` as opposed to `return 1`, so my answer is.

Answer (score 0):

Its your choice.

The standard C library start-up code may well look like:

```
exit(main(argc,argv))
```

Returning from main probably calls exit anyhow. My personal choice would be to return the exit code from main as it does not disguise the flow of the code.